# returning values of computation as String

Tags: java

```
public PaintShopCalculator(int heightFeet, int heightInches,
        int lengthFeet, int lengthInches, int widthFeet, int widthInches) {
    // calculate the total area
    int totalarea = ((widthFeet*12+widthInches)*(lengthFeet*12+lengthInches))
            + 2*((heightFeet*12+heightInches)*(widthFeet*12+widthInches))+ 
            2*((heightFeet*12+heightInches)*(lengthFeet*12+lengthInches));
    //amount of paints needed
    double totalpaint = (totalarea/AREA_PER_GALLON);
    int totalpaint2 = (int) (totalarea/AREA_PER_GALLON);
    double totalprice = 0;
    int fivegallonneeded = 0;
    int onegallonneeded = 0;
    int halfgallonneeded = 0;
    int quartneeded = 0;
    int pintneeded = 0;
    int halfpintneeded = 0;

    if (totalpaint > 0){
        fivegallonneeded = (int)fivegallonneeded + totalpaint2/5 ;
        totalpaint = totalpaint - (fivegallonneeded*5);
        totalpaint2 = totalpaint2 - (fivegallonneeded*5);
        onegallonneeded = (int) onegallonneeded + totalpaint2/1;
        totalpaint = totalpaint - (onegallonneeded*1);
        totalpaint2 = totalpaint2 - (onegallonneeded*1);
        halfgallonneeded = (int) (halfgallonneeded + totalpaint/0.5);
        totalpaint = totalpaint - halfgallonneeded*0.5;
        quartneeded  = (int) (quartneeded + totalpaint/0.25);
        totalpaint = totalpaint - quartneeded*0.25;
        pintneeded = (int) (pintneeded + totalpaint/0.125);
        totalpaint = totalpaint - pintneeded*0.125;
        if (totalpaint > 0){
            halfpintneeded += 1;
        }
    // total price  
    totalprice = (fivegallonneeded * FIVEGALLONS) + (onegallonneeded * ONEGALLON) + (halfgallonneeded* HALFGALLON) 
            +(quartneeded * QUART) +(pintneeded * PINT) +(halfpintneeded * HALFPINT);
```

I'm currently working on a project which computes the price of paint needed to paint a room. I've already done the computation perfectly but now I need some idea of how to return them as string (e.g totalprice, fivegallonneeded) in order to print out a receipt that tells the customer the estimation of the amount of paint required and price.

Comment: It's going to be worth working through a few tutorials on the various [data structures that Java supports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) for you. In this case, a hash map would be quite useful, but only after you learn which other data structures you might be able to use, and see why those aren't as suited.

Comment: Implement `toString()` (constructors don't "return" anything)

Comment: This seems like too much logic for a constructor. Further, you cannot return data from a ctor - you can set instance variables and provide accessors.

Comment: I think your parameters is too long. Make it short

Answer (score 1):

Return an object that contains all the customer needs.

Consider adding these to a method, which would return the object, instead of using a Constructor.

So basically your class would be:

```
public class PaintShopCalculator {

    public RetObject calculateStuff(int heightFeet, int heightInches,
        int lengthFeet, int lengthInches, int widthFeet, int widthInches) {
    // calculate the total area
    int totalarea = ((widthFeet*12+widthInches)*(lengthFeet*12+lengthInches))
            + 2*((heightFeet*12+heightInches)*(widthFeet*12+widthInches))+ 
            2*((heightFeet*12+heightInches)*(lengthFeet*12+lengthInches));
    //amount of paints needed
    double totalpaint = (totalarea/AREA_PER_GALLON);
    int totalpaint2 = (int) (totalarea/AREA_PER_GALLON);
    double totalprice = 0;
    int fivegallonneeded = 0;
    int onegallonneeded = 0;
    int halfgallonneeded = 0;
    int quartneeded = 0;
    int pintneeded = 0;
    int halfpintneeded = 0;

    if (totalpaint > 0){
        fivegallonneeded = (int)fivegallonneeded + totalpaint2/5 ;
        totalpaint = totalpaint - (fivegallonneeded*5);
        totalpaint2 = totalpaint2 - (fivegallonneeded*5);
        onegallonneeded = (int) onegallonneeded + totalpaint2/1;
        totalpaint = totalpaint - (onegallonneeded*1);
        totalpaint2 = totalpaint2 - (onegallonneeded*1);
        halfgallonneeded = (int) (halfgallonneeded + totalpaint/0.5);
        totalpaint = totalpaint - halfgallonneeded*0.5;
        quartneeded  = (int) (quartneeded + totalpaint/0.25);
        totalpaint = totalpaint - quartneeded*0.25;
        pintneeded = (int) (pintneeded + totalpaint/0.125);
        totalpaint = totalpaint - pintneeded*0.125;
        if (totalpaint > 0){
            halfpintneeded += 1;
        }
    // total price  
    totalprice = (fivegallonneeded * FIVEGALLONS) + (onegallonneeded * ONEGALLON) +
      (halfgallonneeded* HALFGALLON) 
            +(quartneeded * QUART) +(pintneeded * PINT) +(halfpintneeded * HALFPINT); 


    RetObject ret = new RetObject();
    // put stuff into the retObject
    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: in adition to that, do as @Bohemian said, implement toString() method.